# How to pass the value from one activity to others(do not navigate to others)

Tags: android

From my **first activity**:

```
musicGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupForMusic);
turnOn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOn);
turnOff = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOff);
musicGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
     if(turnOff.isChecked()) {
       int musicOff = 0;
       mediaPlayer.pause();
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("music off",musicOff);
       startActivity(intent);
     }
     else if(turnOn.isChecked()) {
       int musicOn = 1;
       mediaPlayer.start();
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("music on",musicOn);
       startActivity(intent);
     }
   }
});
```

and this is my **second activity**:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int musicOn = intent.getIntExtra("music on",0);
if(musicOn==1) {
   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HighScoreActivity.this,R.raw.song);
   mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
   mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

At the moment, when I choose whatever `radio button`, it will navigate to my **second activity**, which is not what I want, I just want to control the background music from the **first activity** and make it effects on other activities. **I think I should not use `Intent` as it will always navigate to second activity**

Thanks for any suggest.

Comment: Use broadcast recievers instead

Comment: then you are using the wrong thing try to use shared preferences it will save the data in memory .so you can use it frm other activity

Comment: the best and recommended way is to use broadcast reciever

Comment: i am no idea how to use broadcast reciever...

Comment: I put you two complete sample both with broadcast and with shared peference @BohuaJia

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", value);
startActivityForREsult(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass value to another activity is using Bundle.

Just create a Bundle object and add your passing parameters to it.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

add value to that bundle like
bundle.putString("key","value");
bundle.putInt("keyInt",value);
```

Now Create an Intent Object and pass bundle object to putExtra Method of intent object.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

This way you will be able to send values to other Activity.

Now to get passed values to another activity.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle =  intent.getExtras();
    String strVal = bundle.getString("key");
    int bytes = bundle.getInt("keyInt");
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do this... soz I am too new

Comment: why do you want to run media player on first activity? I think you should move to second activity and then start the music.

Comment: I try this, it can get the value but always navigate to second act which i dont want :(

Comment: this program is a sample game, and first act is setting

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.
Changes in first activty.

```
musicGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroupForMusic);
musicGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,int checkedId){
        boolean  isMediaPlayerON=false;
        switch(checkedId){
            case R.id.radioButtonMusicOn:
                mediaPlayer.start();
                isMediaPlayerON=true;
            break;
            case R.id.radioButtonMusicOff:
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                isMediaPlayerON=false;
            break;
        }
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this,HighScoreActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("music",isMediaPlayerON);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and in second activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int isMediaPlayerON = intent.getBooleanExtra("music",false);
if(isMediaPlayerON){
   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HighScoreActivity.this,R.raw.song);
   mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
   mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: I try this, but it doesn't work, the program always navigate from the first act to second... :(

Comment: Try updated code and let me know if you facing any trouble.

Comment: my object is "when user press radio button, do not navigate from this act(first activity) to the second one", your code can get the value from the first act but it will navigate to the second one, i want to keep it in my fisrt activtiy :(

Comment: I think I should not use `Intent`

Comment: When you have to start second activity? On Radio Checked Changed or other way..?

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
int musicOnOff = 1;

musicGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupForMusic);
turnOn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOn);
turnOff = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOff);
musicGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if(turnOff.isChecked()){
            musicOnOff = 1;
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("musiconoff", musicOnOff);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(turnOn.isChecked()){
            musicOnOff = 2;
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("musiconoff",musicOnOff);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

In the second `Activity` catch the value by

```
int musicOn = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("musiconoff");
if(musicOn == 1){
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HighScoreActivity.this,R.raw.song);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Instead of using two keys for the `String` passed through the `Intent`, just use one key, which is "**musiconoff**".

And remember to use one variable, which is "**musicOnOff**", to switch the value when `Radio Buttons` are checked. Thus even if you did not check a `Radio Button` the variable has a default value which should be the value according to the checked `Radio Button`.

**EDIT:**
You can switch between `**Radio Buttons**` this way, in order to prevent navigation to the second `Activity` and this will only navigate to the second when they are checked.

```
RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch(checkedId){
            case R.id.radioButtonMusicOn://For Turn On
                //Navigate from here
                break;

            case R.id.radioButtonMusicOff://For Turn Off
                //Navigate from here
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I try this code, but when radio button be pressed, the program still navigate to my second activity, not stay the first activity and affect second one

Comment: It still navigates to the second Activity as you have checked conditions using the Radio Button handler, which are turnOn and turnOff. It is recommended to use the other way of switching among the checkIDs. See the edit.

Comment: I think I **should not** use `Intent` as it will navigate which I dont want

Answer (score 0):

> First approach : SharedPreferences

You should use SharedPreferences for your purpose

```
 Boolean MusicIsOff = true; // whatever you like
 SharedPreferences sf=getSharedPreferences("APP_NAME",0);
 sf.edit().putBoolean("music",MusicIsOff).commit();
```

And later in your activities you can check it by this:

```
SharedPreferences sf=getSharedPreferences("APP_NAME",0);
Boolean musicIndicatior=sf.getBoolean("music",false); // false means if i never set this parameter, what is the default value
```

you can access it anywhere you like.

> Second approach : Broadcast Receivers

There is also another approach which will solve your problem.
using Broadcast receivers. i advise you to use the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library as its so easy to use and will handle everything for you. You can use it by just adding a few lines to your project.

first add this to your gradle file:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

then in all your activities in which you want to receive the broadcast when user change the radio button, add these lines.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(Boolean event) {
   /* Do something */
};
```

And at the end, when user change the radio button do this:

```
Boolean music=true;
EventBus.getDefault().post(music);
```

Comment: I try first one, maybe misunderstand, I do this way but it doesnt work.

Comment: `public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,int checkedId){

                if(turnOff.isChecked()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();

                }else if(turnOn.isChecked()){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    SharedPreferences sf=getSharedPreferences("splitBall",0);
                    sf.edit().putBoolean("music",true).commit();
                }

            }`

Comment: in second act do this

Comment: `SharedPreferences sf=getSharedPreferences("splitBall",0);
        Boolean musicIndicatior=sf.getBoolean("music",false);
        if(musicIndicatior==true){
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HighScoreActivity.this,R.raw.song);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }`

Comment: when using shared Preference instead of true , you should put your desired VARIABLE ! see my edit . @BohuaJia

Answer (score 0):

Though other comments say it's better using **Broadcast Receiver** (I think they mean Local Broadcast), I should advise you to use [**EventBus**](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) it is because [unlike Android’s BroadcastReceiver/Intent system, EventBus uses standard Java classes as events and offers a more convenient API.](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/faq/)

you only need to send the message to the **receiving Activity** with something like:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MusicStatusEvent(status));
```

in your `onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)`, so it will become:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
  // Here you send the message if music is on or off.
  EventBus.getDefault().post(new MusicStatusEvent(turnOff.isChecked());
}
```

and the receiving activity must be implementing:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MusicStatusEvent event) {
  /* Do something after you receive the message */
  Log.d("status", "music is" + event.getStatus()? "on" : "off");
};
```

The **MusicStatusEvent** just a simple pojo class:

```
public static class MusicStatusEvent {
   private boolean status;

   public MusicStatusEvent(boolean status) {
     this.status = status;
   }
   public void getStatus() {
     return status;
   }
}
```

for a description of [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), you can read from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38122248/4758255

If you really want to use Broadcast (though I do not recommend it), you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25246377/4758255

Comment: can u give me an example? I am not too sure how to do this

Comment: you can read from https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Communicating-with-an-Event-Bus, for the sample apps you can look at https://github.com/kevintanhongann/EventBusSample

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In Your First Activity:-

```
musicGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupForMusic);
turnOn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOn);
turnOff = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOff);
musicGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if(turnOff.isChecked()){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("musicOff",true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(turnOn.isChecked()){
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("musicOff",false);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

And in second activity:-

```
Boolean musicOff = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("musicOff", true);
if(musicOff){
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HighScoreActivity.this,R.raw.song);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mediaPlayer.start();
}
```